# Explanation on SELECT COUNT() in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have some questions relating to use of count in MySql.

I have used count in many scenario and in every situation its behaves differently. Please explain these

Query #1

```
SELECT count(abc)  (throws an error as "Unknown column" in field list)
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT count('abc')   (this returns 1)
```

Query #3:

```
SELECT count('abc hty')    (this also returns 1 )
```

Please explain reasons to me.

Comment: Please clear that what is abc and abc hty.

Comment: Its Simply abc , nothing special in it. you can replace it to xyz as well.

Comment: did you mean it is column of any table?

Comment: Unknown colom in field list occurs if there is no column with that name in table

Comment: Yes you are right @Shibon , but why next two queries returns 1?

Comment: And further more i have not mentioned any table to select column.

Comment: i thinking in 2nd and 3rd case th query may consider as string count('abc')

Answer (score 1):

Here how it works http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Basically it returns the number of not NULL rows.

1) Your are specifying a column that doesn't exist

2) 3) Your are specifying a constant value, so it just returns the number of rows in the table. Except since you did not specify a table, it returns 1.

Comment: There is no `from` clause in any of the questions, therefore there is no table :)

Comment: right, so maybe this helps: select 'abc' returns a single row of an anonymous column, being the count an aggregate function it is counting the result of this select query